# dokuwiki: catlist: update all namespace titles at once

Tags: dokuwiki

In DokuWiki we have the `catlist` plugin/tag which lists namespaces hierarchically. For reasons we start DokuWiki occasionally with empty caches initially. In our main page we have a

```
~~NOCACHE~~
<catlist -sortAscending -noHead -noAddPageButton -nsLinks:force>
```

part which shows the namespace paths, not the namespace titles initially. For example it shows `certificate_generation` instead of `Certificate generation`. If I hit *Refresh* on my browser then approximately 5 of them gets updated. If I hit *Refresh* again then 5 more. This page now has about 70 items now and is growing. The pages I'm interested in currently are at the bottom, so I need 12..15 *Refresh* to see human readable names of those namespaces.

I would like this indexing / cache updating / what not to run at startup for the whole site under Dokuwiki without user interaction.

I have searched Google for a solution and visited tons of unrelated pages because I could not even figure out how to search for this problem properly. I haven't found any pages that are speaking remotely about this problem.

An ugly workaround would be to call `doku.php` in a loop with an exit condition that its contents does not change anymore.

Comment: Do you still have this issue ? I you do, please contact the maintainer of the plugin (me) and/or open an issue on github. This is a bug.